# What's a simple way to raise ValidationError in action-decorated method?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'd like my decoration actions to be able to raise ValidationErrors in certain cases. How should I implement that in a simple way, or at least to return a 400 error with error json?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out: I should raise an APIException, which encloses the detail message in json.